# How to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty} \frac{cosx}{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x}=0$$

I need to prove that. It's probably very easy but I can't figure it out.

Comment: $|\cos x|\le 1$ for all $x$

Comment: Try bounding the function $\cos x/x$ above and below with similar-looking functions.  Show that these bounds also go to 0 as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah I can see it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove this is using the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). Note that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$$
Now, try dividing both sides by $x$ and take the limit as $x \to \infty$ on your bounds.

Comment: Ohh you're right..it's been a long time since i've studied these things! Thanks for helping me.